# Data grid inside list view as item template and Read Data from Database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have created a project through WPF and my code as below

```
    <UserControl.Resources>                     
        <x:Array x:Key="OrderDataGridItems" Type="{x:Type system:String}">
            <system:String>1</system:String>
            <system:String>2</system:String>
            <system:String>3</system:String>
        </x:Array>      
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWithDataGrid" >
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource OrderDataGridItems}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                                        Width="*" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                                        Width="*" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid> 
        </DataTemplate>       
     </UserControl.Resources>

    Triggers>

    <Grid>         
     <ListView x:Name="CustomersOrderList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWithDataGrid}" >    
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the above code works only for the static resource values(in OrderDataGridItems). this CustomersOrderList inside listview works fine with database values. my requirement is to get and fill all the data from database in both  DataTemplate and ListView from the database,is it possible?? or please help me to get the this solution work, your help greatly appreciated, thank you in-advance for our support.

Comment: You can bind the ItemsSource of the DataGrid in the ItemTemplate to any IEnumerable. Where and how is the data that you want to display in the DataGrid defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create `Templates` until and unless you are not reusing those templates. To make this simple, I've given below sample code to populate a `DataGrid` with data from external sources.

View -

```
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderDataGridItems }" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding CountryName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind - You should have this in ViewModel if following MVVM.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<CountryData> orderDataGridItems;
    public List<CountryData> OrderDataGridItems
    {
        get { return orderDataGridItems; }
        set
        {
            orderDataGridItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OrderDataGridItems");
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        var listFromDataBase = new List<CountryData>();
        listFromDataBase.Add(new CountryData { CountryName ="India"});

        OrderDataGridItems = listFromDataBase;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply as you instructed i cages as below but throws exception

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWidthDataGrid" >
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderDataGridItems}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="*" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Width="*" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
             </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>

Comment: and the Code Behind

 

private void GetOrderDetail()
{                try
                {                               DataTable dtKitchenOrders = transactionService.GetItemDetailsForKitchenOrder();                               OrderDataGridItems.Items.Clear();                                 OrderDataGridItems.ItemsSource = dtKitchenOrders.DefaultView;
                                OrderDataGridItems.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
}

Comment: the exception cpmes as "Error Description:The name 'OrderDataGridItems' does not exist in the current context Kitchen"

Comment: Thank you once again for your support , Now the applications runs but no data showing on the grid (binding also works fine ) for your information i will provide the code below

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWidthDataGrid" >
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderDataGridItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="6,6,6,0" Height="401.96"
   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"><DataGrid.Columns><DataGridTextColumn Header="OrderNo" Width="*" Binding="{Binding OrderNo}" /> <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ItemDescription}"/> </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid></DataTemplate>

Comment: Code Behind
private DataTable orderDataGridItems;
public DataTable OrderDataGridItems
{
                get { return orderDataGridItems; }
                set
         {  orderDataGridItems = value;
                                NotifyChange("OrderDataGridItems");        }
}private void NotifyChange(string v)
{  throw new NotImplementedException();}
private void GetOrderDetail(){   try  {   ataTable dtKitchenOrders = transactionService.GetItemDetailsForKitchenOrder();                                orderDataGridItems = (DataTable)dtKitchenOrders; }
 catch (Exception ex)  {     }}

Comment: Hi Sham , thank you so much for your support , according to way you mentioned i am getting the results but not the way i expect , i can show you by images and unfortunately i cant upload to the stack overflow because there is no option to upload, if you can kindly give me your mail i can send the current look of the layout and the expected layout images , thank you once again for your unforgettable, grate support. waiting for your reply

Comment: Is data displayed in `DataGrid`? You may post new question for new issues.

Comment: the data display in a grid but no columns , i have followed every detail you mentioned i think its issue with the way i bind, because i dont get columns at all, as you mentioned i have post a new question with screenshots , if you have time really appreciate if you can have a look , thank you so much for your support so far. hear is the link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608013/wpf-cards-in-list-view-doesnt-create-dynamically

Comment: i have marked as correct answer , but the issue even we connect the binding with xaml we are not getting the expected out put , if you kindly can suggest a solution by looking at the nature , support is highly greatly ,appreciated, i am deeply sorry about bothering you with regards to this question